# HTML5 simultaneously sounds iOs with Starling

Tags: ios, html, starling-framework

AFAIK it is not possible to play multiple sounds simultaneously with HTML5/JS in iOS.
But I was wondering if it is possible to have a Starling SWF embedded in your webpage and let that play sounds?
So your JS sends requests to the SWF to play audio tracks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to do that in web, but not in iOS since iOS doesnt support Flash.

You can also create one web app for sound streaming, which will stream multiple sounds into one based on the user request.

alot work to do, but afaik only way to mimic multiple sounds inside html5.

and, you dont need starling for sounds, you can use regular flash swf